# Unity Zenject Как получить все объекты класса?

Tags: unity3d, zenject

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
PlayerPresenter - монобех. Их несколько на сцене.
Я пытаюсь сделать так, что бы zenject создал для каждого PlayerPresenter свою PlayerModel.
А затем я хочу получить список всех созданных Zenject'ом PlayerModel'и.
Сейчас в playerModels показывается только один элемент.